# share a domain name beween php and mono

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, mono, domain-name

I've got a problem : I've got a dedicated server where I use three different domain names and php. Now, I've got a new website that I developped with asp.net. I installed mono, mod_mono and transfered my assembly inside `/var/www/mysite`

My problem comes up when I try to access my website. I tried IpAdress/mysite/ but it just gives the three and if I want "IpAddress/mysite/Controller1/Action1" it says 404.

As I said my server is apache and is used with php websites which has several domain names. 
As one of those domain name can be used for my own website, I tried to create a subdomain name let's say `mysite.maindomain.com`
Here is the content of the file `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/mysite.maindomain.com`

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.maindomain.com
    ServerAdmin web-admin@mysite
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

    MonoServerPath sousdomaine.domaineprincipal.com "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server2"
    MonoSetEnv mysite.maindomain.com MONO_IOMAP=all


    MonoApplications mysite.maindomain.com "/:/var/www/mysite"
    <Location "/">
      Allow from all
      Order allow,deny
      MonoSetServerAlias mysite.maindomain.com
      SetHandler mono
      SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
    </Location>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
    </IfModule>
  </VirtualHost>
```

When I call mysite.maindomain.com it says "137 ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED"

What configuration must I give to make mysite.maindomain.com or IpAdress/mysite/ work?

Comment: You might get a better response asking this question on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I post there. Hope they'll have the answer.